# Android SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission Still shown after remove in manifest

Tags: android, android-permissions

i included the `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>`in the Manifest to use, Now i removed it, clean and rebuild the project but its still showing "the permit drawing over other apps" dialog which is grey 
What should i do  to fully remove this permission?

[see pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ofbFu.png)

Answer (score 1):

remove the code from your main java file